# Must read questions in Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

I know you can mark questions you like as favorite for easy reference. But still, you need to go through fairly large number of questions, users profile to find out the real pearls.

Do we have a place we you store any list of interesting questions (*and thus interesting answers as well*). Perhaps like, the most answered question, the most favorited question, the most viewed question, the most upvoted question?

We would need some sort of page where you can put at this detail. Perhaps for every good (*programming*) tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could search for questions (or answers) with more than a specified number of votes:

> [votes:50](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A50)

Or if you wanted to see questions with a certain count of answers:

> [answers:66](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A66)

Of certain views:

> [views:616](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A616)

Coupled with tags in the search term, I think this covers most of what you want.

Comment: ChrisF 6,666●7●19 - Are you are the father of the beast?

Comment: @voyager - you've seen my kids then ;)

Comment: Thnx ChrisF. As it seems, I will use search.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use your Favorites to bookmark things to go back to later.

If you want to find things with certain users, certain votes and other criteria like that, you can use the super ninja search options.

https://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Thanks ThxTXI. Wish I could upvote. Need 15 rptn for that. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since compiling lists of really good questions and answers isn't really what SO is *for* (it's for getting answers to questions), I wouldn't suggest that this functionality be added to SO by Atwood's Angels.

**However**, I can see a benefit for having high-quality questions and answers be in a very visible location. Especially for questions that are asked a lot and have been answered well to death already.

Perhaps someone could create a community wiki question on meta for people to list really awesome questions whose answers benefit everybody even if they don't have the particular problem the original asker had intended? I'm talking about questions that are so good that just reading them make you a better person or head in a jar or raised chicken or whatever you might be.

Comment: You are onto something. What about a new question ordering tab, using not votes, but favourites...

Comment: This is what I am looking for. A page where I could see the best of answers. For questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon. I don't need to have to ask question.