# Must read questions/answers/concepts - language wise

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, languages

This question is almost related to [another question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/must-read-questions-in-stackoverflow). It is about finding the good question easy for reading and referring to it later. But then, I was asked to use search.

Now, I guess it is right time to reiterate the same request with a slight change. Think of Wikibooks or some sort that stuff. The language wise collection to include various top questions and important, interesting top answers, the answers can contain comments and examples to make the reading easy. It can be problem book with answers, starting from simple questions to advanced concepts.

I know it is little too much of asking in a Q&A site. But the truth is there are many people like me, who browse through SO to find good questions, techniques in language of our interest and learn concepts that way, this approach will make life easier for lot of us. If there is a proper mechanism/tool, people can compile a good collection of question through which one can learn language/technique.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was looking for and I guess is a great attempt.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info

Answer (score 2):

Some features you might find useful.

1. Each tag has a 'faq', where most often referenced questions are presented. [An example with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/faq)
2. Tag descriptions often include references to useful resources. [Again javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Comment: +1. Correct. Thanks. But what if I decide to learn a language and like to go through some interesting questions / answers? I know SO is not a site which offers tutorials, but why not? we already have the content with little more effort we can manage a good compilation for bunch of languages. I know I am asking bit too much here, but why not?

Comment: @Guru FAQ already provides pretty good selection of questions, don't you think? Many of them can be interesting to beginners and advanced users alike. Or, do you mean you want to create a tutorial from questions? In this case, you can start in your personal blog and if it turns out any good, we can add such feature on SO.